# how to make a demo to access the site on drupal 7

Tags: drupal, frontend, backend

I need to make a demo access to the site. To which a user can enter. And after a few hours, he did reset to the previous settings. [Example](http://www.opensourcecms.com/scripts/details.php?scriptid=191).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can create a new user role just for demoing(limit access to only what you need). And add a cron job to restore a snapshot of database every few hours.